# Why can't ed be exited with C-c?

Tags: less, interrupt, ed

The program `ed`, a minimal text editor, cannot be exited by sending it an interrupt through using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, instead printing the error message "?" to the console.  Why doesn't `ed` just exit when it receives the interrupt?  Surely there's no reason why a cryptic error message is more useful here than just exiting.  This behavior leads many new users into the following sort of interaction:

> ```
> $ ed
> hello
> ?
> help
> ?
> exit
> ?
> quit
> ?
> ^C
> ?
> ^C
> ?
> ?
> ?
> ^D
> $ su
> # rm -f /bin/ed
> ```

Such a tragic waste—easily avoidable if `ed` simply agreed to be interrupted.

Another stubborn program exhibiting similar behavior is `less` which also doesn't appear to have much reason to ignore `C-c`.  Why don't these programs just take a hint?

Comment: Interactive applications are not the same as non-interactive. The Ctrl-C behavior you are used to is the default for non-interactive ones. The interactive ones may override the behavior of Ctrl-C for their own purposes.

Comment: Also, not sure if [joke](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html)

Comment: @jw013 Yes, the "typical session" was a joke (I couldn't find that one for some reason) but my question is serious.  What I don't understand is *why* these applications choose to override the behavior of Ctrl-C if it doesn't actually provide anything useful.

Comment: Since this question comes up as a top google search answer to "how to exit ed," I'd like to add here that it's just 'q' followed by a return. Many Bothans died to bring us this information.

Comment: @Dmitri Why not bold-font this here? **Exit ed** via `q` **+** `Enter`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_(POSIX)#SIGINT). The conventional action for SIGINT is to return to a program's toplevel loop, cancelling the current command and entering a mode where the program waits for the next command. Only non-interactive programs are supposed to die from SIGINT.

So it's natural that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't kill ed, but causes it to return to its toplevel loop. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> aborts the current input line and returns to the ed prompt.

The same goes for less: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> interrupts the current command and brings you back to its command prompt.

For historical reasons, ed ignores [SIGQUIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGQUIT#SIGQUIT) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>). Normal applications should not catch this signal and allow themselves to be terminated, with a core dump if enabled.

Answer (score 21):

The [Unix V7 `ed(1)` source code](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/ed.c) is a primitive 1,762-line C program with just a few comments, one of which is this highly-enlightening header comment:

```
/*
 * Editor
 */
```

Given that the source code itself does not provide any rationale, you're only going to get it from the program's author.

`ed` was originally written [by Ken Thompson in PDP-11 assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)#History_and_influence), but it was ported to C by [Dennis Ritchie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie), who created C for Unix, then used it to make Unix portable to non-PDP machines. Alas, Dr Ritchie is no longer around to answer such questions.

My reading of the code suggests that it was done to try and preserve the contents of the [in-core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic-core_memory) copy of the edited document. You'll notice that other text editors also do not die on <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>.

Here's what `ed` does on <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>:

```
onintr()
{
    signal(SIGINT, onintr);
    putchr('\n');
    lastc = '\n';
    error(Q);
}
```

(Yes, [K&R C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K.26R_C). We don't need no steenkin' return type specifiers or parameter declarations.)

Translated into English, `ed`:

1. Re-registers the signal handler.¹
2. Writes out a new line and remembers that it did so via the global variable² `lastc`.
3. Calls the `error()` function, which [famously](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html) does little more than print `?`, from the user's perspective.

In other words, it's saying, "You didn't really mean to do that, did you?"

---

**Footnotes:**

1. Unix didn't get auto-resetting signals [until 4.3BSD](https://archive.org/details/designimplementa0000unse/page/97/mode/1up?q=auto-reset), released in the mid-1980s. See the first bullet point under "Comparison with Other Systems."
2. `ed.c` has about *sixty* global variables!

Comment: Also worth noting that a lot of text editors do not exit on Control-C. Vim also doesn't. Neither does nano. I don't think emacs does, either, but don't have it installed to test.

Comment: @derobert Vi treats Ctrl+C the Unix way: go back to the toplevel. Emacs has its own keybindings, due to its non-Unix origins; the Emacs equivalent of Unix's Ctrl+C is Ctrl+G (the bell character — ring the bell at the computer to interrupt it)

Comment: @derobert: Fair point. I've added this to the answer.

Comment: @Gilles: One of the side effects of calling `error(s)` in `ed.c` is to return to the main processing loop. It does so with a `longjmp()` call. *shudder*

Comment: Thank you for the details and the history lesson. This was a great read!

Answer (score 8):

`ed`, like other interactive programs, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt tasks of the program itself.
This is very similar to the normal case, where it interrupts a task running in the shell - a command.

From the user perspective, both variants are very similar.
The handling of the signal is different: in the usual case, the signal `SIGINT` is sent to the foreground process, a running command, and the command handles it by exiting.
In the case of `ed`, the signal is sent to the foreground process, the `ed` instance. If there is a task running in `ed`, it is interrupted and the prompt is shown. If there is no task running, nothing is changed.

Note how a shell also does not exit on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, just like `ed`. And that it does exit on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Again, just like `ed`

Answer (score 4):

There are three signals that `ed` cares about:

1. `INT`
2. `HUP`
3. `QUIT`

[The POSIX specification of `ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/ed.html) says the following about these:

> `SIGINT`
>
> The `ed` utility shall interrupt its current activity, write the string `?\n` to standard output, and return to command mode (see the EXTENDED DESCRIPTION section).
>
> `SIGHUP`
>
> If the buffer is not empty and has changed since the last write, the `ed` utility shall attempt to write a copy of the buffer in a file. First, the file named `ed.hup` in the current directory shall be used; if that fails, the file named `ed.hup` in the directory named by the `HOME` environment variable shall be used. In any case, the `ed` utility shall exit without writing the file to the currently remembered pathname and without returning to command mode.
>
> `SIGQUIT`
>
> The `ed` utility shall ignore this event.

So whatever implementation of `ed` you are using, it conforms to the POSIX specification with regards to the `INT` signal (which is what <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> sends).

In this regard, the editor behaves like an interactive shell, which also does not terminate upon receiving the `INT` signal. Other editors, such as `vi` and `nano` does the same thing.

Comment: Some program implementations deliberately contradict POSIX, so it might be useful to explain the rationale for the standard / the cost of breaking it in this case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605463/how-to-use-posixly-correct-in-grep

Comment: @sourcejedi The standard does not say anything about the signals in its rationale. I have found no rationale saying anything about _why the standard is followed_ in the sources of `ed` that I have available. It behaves in a similar manner as the shell, which also does not terminate on receiving the `INT` signal.